# How do I connect phpmyadmin to mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to create a web server on raspberry pi, to take data from hardware. I've successfully created the server and also logged into phpmyadmin, Now, i'm creating a database in phpmyadmin, and getting this error,
mysqli_real_connect():(HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
&
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed

Please give me a sloution, doing this for my FYP and really new to this

I've created phpmyadmin, when i was downloading it on raspberry terminal, it did give me an error, at first i retried it but then I ignored it and continued and now I think it's now link it with wordpress

I expected for it to create a database through phpmyadmin for wordpress. Now, it's not happening

Comment: Do you have a mysql server set up on localhost? That would be a prerequisite here. Get your mysql database server up and running, then install phpmyadmin. As part of the set up it will ask for root password to the mysql database and do it's necessary work.

Comment: Yes, all of that is done, I have already setup mysql server

Comment: When you sign into phpmyadmin are you signing in with a mysql user that has access to create a database in your mysql database?

Comment: yes, it is the same user 'root' that i use to sign in mysql

Comment: Great! It sounds like that it's trying to connect in with it's own `phpmyadmin` username (perhaps to check some metadata where it doesn't act as root). As part of the set up ( I think) it creates the phpmyadmin user as well as a database for storing metadata (phpmyadmin UI information, like a web application generally would). Does that `phpmyadmin` database exist on the server? If not you may have a bad install. You can step again through the installation steps by issuing `dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` and this time note what is erroring.

Comment: If `phpmyadmin` database exists and there are tables in there, then check to see if the `phpmyadmin@localhost` user exists. If it doesn't then you may want to `dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` still to see why it's not being created.

Comment: How should I check if `phpmyadmin` database exist on the server? and if i do have bad install, how can I fix it?

Comment: Apologies for the wait. On your command line you can log into your server `mysql -u root -p` and supply the password. Then 'SHOW DATABASES' and see if there is one for `phpmyadmin`. The fix for the bad install will be that `dpkg-reconfigure` command. that will rerun the post installation steps for that package which will present you with all the prompts for phpmyadmin install once again.

Comment: So, there isn't a database with the name phpmyadmin, but there is a table that I created in phpmyadmin. Does that mean it's connected?

Comment: It seems unlikely that it would run at all if there was no meta database for your phpmyadmin installation. Perhaps you specified a different schema/database name when you set up phpmyadmin. Look for tables with the `pma_` prefix. I can't imagine that it would run at all without those tables. You can check out /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php to see how you set it up originally. There will be a `$dbname` variable in there with that information.